# Use jQuery to not check hidden td:s

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the code below to make all checkboxes checked, but the problem is sometimes the checkboxes has a parent `<td>` with style="display:none;" css property and should not be checked.

How can I modify the code below to ignore the invisible checkboxes?

```
// Check / uncheck all checkboxes
$('.check_all').click(function() {
    $(this).parents('form').find('input:checkbox').attr('checked', $(this).is(':checked'));
});`
```

(the reason the `<td>`:s are not visible are due to quicksearch.js)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use the **[:visible](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/)** selector:

```
$(this).parents('form').find('input:checkbox:visible').attr('checked', $(this).is(':checked'));
```